# using <span> and <div> to create a background to text with margins

Tags: css, html

I am currently using this as a `<span>` to style text.

```
.tag {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

However, when I add a few below it all the borders touch each other. As it's a `<span>`, I can't expect them to be able to move, but if I use a `<div>` or style the original `<p>` that the text is in, the background extends to the whole line.

Is the a way of getting the best of both worlds here?

**EDIT**

Following the `display: inline` suggestion, my code is now:

```
.tag {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

You can see how it displays on the right of [this page](http://oxford.guestvibe.com).

Comment: where is the issue that you are mentioning on the page?

Comment: Of the two boxes on top of the image, the one on the right. I'd like to be able to space the text out better.

Comment: Maybe try display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:block` and `display:inline` are different ...  DIVs by default are block ...  spans are inline.  You can, however, change the default behaviour by using the `display:` attribute

Comment: I tried that but it seems 'margin' and 'display: inline' cannot coexist...?

Comment: Sure they can.  It depends on the position: attribute as well.  absolute relative.  These things will cause inline or block to behave differently, but they can, and often do, coexist. You might consider using a wrapper, and setting a width, and using that width to define the "inner" divs width: Set them to block and width of 100%.  If that's the case, you wouldn't need relative or absolute, since it would inherit the width of the parent div.